# A VB Progress Bar that moves on timers interval?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was making a program in Visual Basic 2010, and was wondering if a Progress bar could move accounting on a Timer? If yes, it would be very helpful for my current task.

Answer (score 0):

try this something like this in VB.NET:

```
Do

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep() 

Loop Until ProgressBar1.Value >= ProgressBar1.Maximum
```

http://checktechno.blogspot.com/2013/03/example-progressbar-in-visual-basic.html

or in C#:

```
do {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep();
} while (!(ProgressBar1.Value >= ProgressBar1.Maximum));
```

where "sleep" is set as a constant at 100 ms. You just to dynamically set that value to your timer.